# Typescript Template Literal Syntax Highlighting Issue

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm having an issue that I don't understand. Im using VSCode to do typescript development. The developer tools (In chrome and IE) are not correctly highlighting the syntax in my template literals. 
I've got template literals before this one that work just fine.

A picture says a thousand words so here it is:

[image: Template Literal Syntax Highlighting Issue]

Comment: same here... any idea where to report it?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=679626

Comment: Thank you!! If I remember correctly, I experiences this with multiple browsers. I'll have to investigate a little further, but you pointed me in the correct direction!